# How to project the mat-toolbar-row content one after the other while creating the Custom component by wrapping angular material 6 toolbar component

Tags: typescript, angular6, angular-material-6, ng-content

Actually I am creating a custom component by wrapping the Angular material Toolbar component. I have wrapped the first element mat-toolbar by using ng-content, and also wrapped the second element mat-toolbar-row using ng-content only.

Here i am facing some issue while projecting the second or more than one mat-toolbar-row, because it is not displaying it in the next line as next toolbar-row, it is displaying the second toolbar content in first row only.As I know ng-content is static projection, so it is projecting the second toolbar row in the first row , how can i resolve this issue.

Please the find [stackblitzLink](https://stackblitz.com/edit/toolbar-component) here and I have shown the material example also below the custom component. Please help me in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is still looking for an answer here, I ended up wrapping the `<mat-toolbar-row></mat-toolbar-row>` with a `<ng-container></ng-container>` tag.

Before I had the customized Toolbar component like this:

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    ...
  </mat-toolbar-row>
  <ng-content select="mat-toolbar-row"></ng-content>
</mat-toolbar>
```

And I changed it to this:

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <ng-container>
    <mat-toolbar-row>
      ...
    </mat-toolbar-row>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-content select="mat-toolbar-row"></ng-content>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Somehow the `<ng-container></ng-container>` tag makes the toolbar rows arrange in correct order.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-toolbar [color]="color">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <ng-container select="sq-toolbar-row">
  <mat-toolbar-row >
  </mat-toolbar-row>
  </ng-container>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but could you please explain why this code solves OP's problem? A little explanation, even comments on code, would go a long way